# Reading Philippine License Plate (OCR or ANPR)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-play-services, ocr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I need to read the a license plate issued in the Philippines

[image: ![LICENSE PLATE](https://www.olavsplates.com/foto_r/rp_yec652_close.jpg)]

I tried GooglePlayServices.Vision [TextRecognizer] but it is giving me inaccurate results.

I also tried some sample ANPR apps but the apps is also giving inaccurate results.

I think the reason why it is giving me inaccurate results is because of its backgroud because when I am reading a license plate with black text and white background it is giving me accurate results.

Any advise on how to solve my problem, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the standard plate? I mean if they all look alike, with the clouds etc, you could just pre process them replacing all blueish with white and trimming excess in the bottom. Maybe just playing with contrast would help.